# select elements from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working with jquery and ajax.I want to select json object having same element. ie, here is my json object.

```
 {"data":[{"row":15,"name":"aaa"},
          {"row":15,"name":"bbb"},
          {"row":10,"name":"ffff"},
          {"row":15,"name":"rrr"}
 ]}
```

Then, I want to select all 'name' having same 'row'. How shall I do it using jquery?

Comment: Could you clarify this? What do you mean by selecting all that have the same row? How do you decide which row to get? Will there only ever be 2 different rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.filter()` if you want a pure js solution...

```
success: function(result) {
    var test = 15;
    var subset = result.data.filter(function(o) { return o.row === test; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep for that.

```
var obj = {
    "data": [{
        "row": 15,
        "name": "aaa"
    }, {
        "row": 15,
        "name": "bbb"
    }, {
        "row": 10,
        "name": "ffff"
    }, {
        "row": 15,
        "name": "rrr"
    }]
};

function filterData(rowNumber) {
    var filteredrObject = jQuery.grep(obj.data, function(element, i) {
        return element.row == rowNumber;
    });
    return filteredrObject
}
console.log(filterData(15));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/34/)